# Implementing Lazyloading issues- Angular 8

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Hello i have been having issues implementing lazy loading for the following components
ResourcesComponent, PrivacypolicyComponent, CopyrightinformationComponent, ContactusComponent, DisclaimerComponent.
[image: This is my file directory]

How do i implement lazy loading for the following Routes and component: Resources/contactus, Resources/privacypolicy, Resources/copyrightinformation, Resources/disclaimer and Resources/subs?

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import './vendor';
import { EgisexternalSharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { EgisexternalCoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { EgisexternalAppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { EgisexternalHomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { TwowayauthModule } from './twowayauth/twowayauth.module';
import { ScannerModule } from './scanner/scanner.module';

// jhipster-needle-angular-add-module-import JHipster will add new module here
import { JhiMainComponent } from './layouts/main/main.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './layouts/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { PageRibbonComponent } from './layouts/profiles/page-ribbon.component';
import { ActiveMenuDirective } from './layouts/navbar/active-menu.directive';
import { ErrorComponent } from './layouts/error/error.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from './resources/resources.component';
import { PrivacypolicyComponent } from './resources/privacypolicy/privacypolicy.component';
import { CopyrightinformationComponent } from './resources/copyrightinformation/copyrightinformation.component';
import { DisclaimerComponent } from './resources/disclaimer/disclaimer.component';
import { ContactusComponent } from './resources/contactus/contactus.component';
import { RelatedinformationComponent } from './resources/subs/relatedinformation/relatedinformation.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgxSpinnerModule, NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { EgisexternalAppLoginModule } from './login/login-page.module';
// the scanner!
import { ZXingScannerModule } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner';

@NgModule({
imports: [
 MaterialModule,
 BrowserModule,
 EgisexternalSharedModule,
 EgisexternalCoreModule,
 EgisexternalHomeModule,
 EgisexternalAppApplicationModule,
 
 // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
 EgisexternalAppRoutingModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 TwowayauthModule,
 ScannerModule,
 ZXingScannerModule,

 NgxSpinnerModule
],
declarations: [
 JhiMainComponent,
 NavbarComponent,
 ErrorComponent,
 PageRibbonComponent,
 ActiveMenuDirective,
 FooterComponent,
 ResourcesComponent,
 PrivacypolicyComponent,
 CopyrightinformationComponent,
 DisclaimerComponent,
 ContactusComponent,
 RelatedinformationComponent
],
bootstrap: [JhiMainComponent],
providers: [NgxSpinnerService]
})
export class EgisexternalAppModule {}
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { errorRoute } from './layouts/error/error.route';
import { navbarRoute } from './layouts/navbar/navbar.route';
import { DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED } from 'app/app.constants';

import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core/auth/user-route-access-service';
import { ResourcesComponent } from './resources/resources.component';
import { PrivacypolicyComponent } from './resources/privacypolicy/privacypolicy.component';
import { CopyrightinformationComponent } from './resources/copyrightinformation/copyrightinformation.component';
import { ContactusComponent } from './resources/contactus/contactus.component';
import { DisclaimerComponent } from './resources/disclaimer/disclaimer.component';
import { TwowayauthComponent } from 'app/twowayauth/twowayauth/twowayauth.component';
import { ScannerComponent } from 'app/scanner/scanner.component';

const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [navbarRoute, ...errorRoute];

const MYPortalRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'scanner',
  component: ScannerComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
  path: 'resources/privacypolicy',
  component: PrivacypolicyComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
  path: 'resources/copyrightinformation',
  component: CopyrightinformationComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
  path: 'resources/contactus',
  component: ContactusComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
  path: 'resources/disclaimer',
  component: DisclaimerComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
{
  path: 'resources/auth',
  component: TwowayauthComponent,
  data: {},
  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},

{
  path: 'resources',
  loadChildren: () => import('./resources/resources.module').then(m => m.ResourcesModule)
},

{
  path: 'resources/copyrightinformation',
  loadChildren: () => import('./resources/copyrightinformation/copyrightinformation.module').then(m => m.CopyrightinformationModule)
},


];

@NgModule({
imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild(MYPortalRoutes),
  RouterModule.forRoot(
    [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        data: {
          authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        },
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
        loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin-routing.module').then(m => m.AdminRoutingModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAccountModule)
      },
{
  path: 'resources/contactus',
  loadChildren: () => import('./resources/contactus/contactus.module').then(m => m.ContactusModule)
}

      {
        path: 'application',
        loadChildren: () => import('./application/application.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppApplicationModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'downloads',
        loadChildren: () => import('./downloads/downloads.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppDownloadsModule)
      },

      // {
      //   path: 'scanner',
      //   loadChildren: () => import('./scanner/scanner.module').then(m => m.ScannerModule)
      // },

      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppDashboardModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'propertytaxes',
        loadChildren: () => import('./propertytaxes/propertytaxes.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppPropertySearchModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'search-ctc',
        loadChildren: () => import('./search-ctc/search-ctc.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppSearchCtcModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'link-property',
        loadChildren: () => import('./link-property/link-property.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppLinkPropertyModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'surveyor-acct',
        loadChildren: () => import('./surveyor-acct/surveyor-acct.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppSurveyorAcctModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'onlinecalculator',
        loadChildren: () => import('./onlinecalculator/onlinecalculator.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppOnlinecalculatorModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'trackapplication',
        loadChildren: () => import('./trackapplication/trackapplication.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppTrackapplicationModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'yourproperty',
        loadChildren: () => import('./yourproperty/yourproperty.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppYourpropertyModule)
      },

      // {
      //   path: 'login',
      //   loadChildren: () => import('./login/login-page.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppLoginModule)
      // },

      {
        path: 'user-registeration',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user-registeration/user-registeration.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppUserRegisterationModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'create-account',
        loadChildren: () => import('./create-account/create-account.module').then(m => m.EgisexternalAppCreateAccountModule)
      },
      //

      // EgisexternalAppCreateAccountModule,
      // ,
      // ,

      ...LAYOUT_ROUTES
    ],
    { enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
  )
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EgisexternalAppRoutingModule {}
```

This is my resources.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus/contactus.component';
import { CopyrightinformationComponent } from './copyrightinformation/copyrightinformation.component';
import { DisclaimerComponent } from './disclaimer/disclaimer.component';
import { PrivacypolicyComponent } from './privacypolicy/privacypolicy.component';
import { RelatedinformationComponent } from './subs/relatedinformation/relatedinformation.component';

const RESOURCES: Routes = [
  { path: 'resources/contactus', component: ContactusComponent },
  { path: 'resources/copyrightinformation', component: CopyrightinformationComponent },
  { path: 'resources/disclaimer', component: DisclaimerComponent },
  { path: 'resources/privacypolicy', component: PrivacypolicyComponent },
  { path: 'resources/relatedinformation', component: RelatedinformationComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ContactusComponent,
    CopyrightinformationComponent,
    DisclaimerComponent,
    PrivacypolicyComponent,
    RelatedinformationComponent
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class ResourcesModule {}
```

This is resources.route.ts

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

import { ResourcesComponent } from './resources.component';
import { WorkflowGuard } from '../downloads/workflow/workflow-guard.service';
import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core/auth/user-route-access-service';

export const RESOURCES: Route = {
  path: 'resources',
  component: ResourcesComponent,
  data: {
    authorities: [],
    pageTitle: 'resources.title'
  },
  canActivate: [WorkflowGuard]
};
```

Inside the contact us folder,

i created a contactus-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { errorRoute } from '../.../.../.../.../../../../../../layouts/error/error.route';
import { navbarRoute } from '../.../.../.../.../../../../../../layouts/navbar/navbar.route';
import { DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED } from 'app/app.constants';

import { UserRouteAccessService } from 'app/core/auth/user-route-access-service';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus.component';
import { TwowayauthComponent } from 'app/twowayauth/twowayauth/twowayauth.component';

const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [navbarRoute, ...errorRoute];

const MYPortalRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContactusComponent,
    data: {},
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(LAGOSPortalRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ContactusRoutingModule {}
```

Then my contactus.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ContactusComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [ContactusComponent]
})
export class ContactusModule {}
```

How do i implement lazy loading for the Routes and component: Resources/contactus

Comment: Not sure if I caught the question...

Comment: Indeed a bit unclear what your issue is. One thing that pops out - having a Router.forRoot and a Router.forChild in the same module is a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

I will simply explain the steps with some sample codes.

1. Your root route is the app route and the RoutingModule should look like this. Only the first-level routes are defined here. For example, your Resources Route. I have also added your guards.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'resources', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'resources',
    loadChildren: () => import('./PathToModule/resources.module').then((m) => m.ResourcesModule),
    canActivate: [WorkflowGuard]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

2. Your Resource Module should look like this... The second-level routes are defined within the children array.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ResourcesComponent,
    data: {
    authorities: [],
    pageTitle: 'Resources'
    },
    children: [
      { 
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'contact-us', 
        pathMatch: 'full' 
      },
      { 
        path: 'contact-us',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pathToModule/contactus.module').then(m => m.ContactusModule),
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
      },
      { 
        path: 'copyright-information', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./pathToModule/copyrightinformation.module').then(m => m.CopyrightinformationModule),
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
      },
      { 
        path: 'disclaimer', 
        loadChildren: () => import('./pathToModule/disclaimer.module').then(m => m.DisclaimerModule),
        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

3. In the ContactusRoutingModule and siblings...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContactusComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Contact Us'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Don't forget to add the necessary import statements where they are needed.

Lazyloading children modules can sometimes be trickish but it helps a lot.

Let me know if this helps.